# Azure Devops yaml deployment pipelines shows unwanted message / description

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Recently I migrated from the traditional Graphic deployment pipelines to the reusable yaml build and deployment pipelines.
The yaml build pipelines are delivering (multiple) artifacts which are used in a deployment pipeline.

When running the deployment pipeline (making use of parameters and settings), yaml templates, etc...
I see, when the pipeline is finished, a description like:

> <build id> - <latest check-in message where the deployment pipeline
> is located>

Since the deployment pipeline is not located in the same repo as the build pipelines, the message/description does not relate to the actual state.

Is it possible to change these messages/descriptions so when I display the runs of the pipeline I can see what is important for me, instead of the last check-in message?

Thanks, Bart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This pipeline setting will stop it adding the commit description when it prints the pipeline run name:

```
appendCommitMessageToRunName: false
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pipeline?view=azure-pipelines#pipeline-stages

Note: this is a new feature as of September 2022; previously, the commit message was always shown.

Comment: And when will this be available?
       appendCommitMessageToRunName: false  Is not available

Comment: the [release notes dated 12th September](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/sprint-209-update) say *These features will roll out over the next two to three weeks.*