# How do I change the name of the pipeline run in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Azure Pipelines shows the pipeline run as the last commit message.  I want to override that since my pipeline is triggered by a pipeline completion trigger and I want to note what it is that triggered when I am looking at the list of runs.

Is that possible?

I am talking about updating the description and not [updating the build number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046481/how-do-i-update-buildnumber-using-powershell/37048559#37048559)

Comment: Potentially duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37048559/736079

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Devops yaml deployment pipelines shows unwanted message / description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70171440/azure-devops-yaml-deployment-pipelines-shows-unwanted-message-description)

Answer (score 5):

You can add in your pipeline yaml parameters:

```yaml
name: MyName
appendCommitMessageToRunName: false
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pipeline?view=azure-pipelines#pipeline-jobs

Answer (score -1):

You can't update the description. The only thing you can do is generate a more useful buildnumber.